# How to copy files in ODB (personal sites) using pnp powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

This works for sharepoint site:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1" -UseWebLogin
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl "Shared Documents/1GB.csv" -TargetUrl "/sites/site2/Shared Documents" -Force
```

But doing the same for ODB site is not working:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_tenant_com" -UseWebLogin
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl "1GB.csv" -TargetUrl "1GB_1.csv" -Force
```

Above code gives 403 error. I am using admin to login.

I also tried

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/" -UseWebLogin
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl "personal/user_tenant_com/1GB.csv" -TargetUrl "personal/user_tenant_com/1GB_1.csv" -Force
```

Above code gives "no such file or folder." error.